# WCF Test client showing 1 endpoint, while Config file exposing 3 endpoints

Tags: asp.net, .net, wcf

I have a WCF web service with exposing 3 end points.
But when I debug it to WCF test client it is only showing one basicHttpBinding endpoint.

1 : **Why so?**

2 : Here I have one operation contract "CallADSWebMethod" which returns a DataContract (VINDescription)..Just curious to know..**why this works great for me in real time but still it is not testable by test client**..I mean Test client says "This operation is not supported by test client"

3 : Here in the endpointBehaviors - I have only given  and no ...But still it is working from jquery ajax call..**So what is the significance of "enableWebScript" ??**

[image: Test client Image]

Config Info

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="asmx" name="ADSChromeVINDecoder.Service">
        <endpoint address="basic"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  name="httpEndPoint"
                  contract="ADSChromeVINDecoder.IService"/>
        <endpoint address="json"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
                  name="webEndPoint"
                  contract="ADSChromeVINDecoder.IService"/>
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="asmx">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WCF Test Client will only show the **SOAP** endpoints - and there's only one of those (the one with the `basicHttpBinding`).

- The `json` endpoint uses `webHttpBinding` (which is **REST** based - can't be tested by WCF Test Client)
- The `mex` endpoint is the metadata exchange endpoint - not a *real* service endpoint.

Therefore, the WCF Test Client correctly show only one (SOAP) endpoint - there **is** only one!

**Update:** the WCF Test Client is rather limited, and one of the limits is that it cannot deal with your own custom datatypes as parameters. You can basically only test methods with parameters of type `int`, `string`, `datetime` and the like - the simplistic data types.

If you need more advanced web service testing, you should check out the (freely available) [SoapUI tool](http://www.soapui.org/) for testing your SOAP web services - including complex parameter types and a lot more.

Comment: In the same one operation contract "CallADSWebMethod" which returns a DataContract (VINDescription)..Just curious to know..why this works great for me in real time but still it is not testable by test client..I mean Test client says "This operation is not supported by test client"

Comment: @Learner: the WCF Test Client is rather limited, and one of the limits is that it cannot deal with your own custom datatypes as parameters. You can basically only test methods with parameters of type `int`, `string`, `datetime` and the like - the simplistic data types.

Comment: Ok..So might be the new version of WCF test client will come with this.

Comment: @Learner: I haven't heard anything either way - but I personally highly doubt that the WCF Test Client will be improved much ..... use SoapUI instead !

Comment: @Learner: see [MSDN documentation on EnableWebScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675191.aspx): *This element enables the endpoint behavior that makes it possible to consume the service from ASP.NET AJAX web pages.* - also [see this blog post here elaborating a bit more](http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2011/03/29/calling-wcf-web-services-from-javascript.aspx)

Comment: Got it..I was confusing ASP.NET ajax with jQuery ajax.